# Windows XP unknown location popup annoyance

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I'm plagued by a popup from Windows XP when I use wireless.  It says, "You are in an Unknown Location..."  It always pops above whatever window I'm using, but does not take focus, so while it does not interrupt my typing, it gets in the way and I can't dismiss it with a keystroke.

I'd like to find a way to disable this popup.  I've searched in control panel --> Network Connections.

I'm not referring to "balloon tips" that appear related to the wireless connection in a new location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like extra wireless software which comes loaded onto your computer when you bought it. This software can also get loaded inadvertently when you install your drivers after a clean install.

Windows XP does a fine job of managing your wireless networks so having this additional software is not only redundant, but cause lots of little issues like the one you are talking about.

I would suggest following this guide:

http://oit.pdx.edu/use-windows-to-manage-wireless

Comment: Thanks.  This is a computer set up by our desktop support staff and I imagine they have their reasons for using a third party product to manage the wireless.